# jQuery Autocomplete with Ajax Suggetion Not Return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So simple to set jQuery Autocomplete is not working for me why i am strange for this can you please check what is problem in this?

> **Jquery Function**

```
$("#location_suggetion").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request,response) {
        $.ajax ({
            url: base_url+'data_check/get_location',
            data: {term: request.term},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                response( $.map( data.suggestions, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }));    
            } 
        });
    },
});
```

> **PHP File Code**

```
$term = $this->input->get('term');
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tb_cities` WHERE name LIKE "'.$term.'%" LIMIT 0,6');
$results = $query->result();
$html = '';
$html.= '[';
foreach($results as $result){
    $html.= '{ label: "'.$result->name.', '.get_country_row($result->country_id)->name.'", value: "'.$result->name.'" },';
}
$html.='];';

echo $html;
```

> **Console Get me Result**

```
[{ label: "Rangat, India", value: "Rangat" },{ label: "Rajahmundry, India", value: "Rajahmundry" },{ label: "Rajamahendri, India", value: "Rajamahendri" },{ label: "Rajampet, India", value: "Rajampet" },{ label: "Rajendranagar, India", value: "Rajendranagar" },{ label: "Rajoli, India", value: "Rajoli" },];
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is the ajax call sent and return with status 200 (OK)?

Comment: No errors in console and return properly @MoshFeu

Comment: your json data is wrong in console.

Comment: no @Suchit json data is peroper in console

Comment: @BhavinSasapra i have given a link in answer,Please test your data there. And that is not a good way to construct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonp` is used for `cross domain` request. Use `json` instead. Your JSON date in console is wrong check [here](http://json.parser.online.fr) . To convert the array in JSON string use `json_encode`. Change your php code to this:

```
$term = $this->input->get('term');
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tb_cities` WHERE name LIKE "'.$term.'%" LIMIT 0,6');
$results = $query->result();

$html= array();$i=0;

foreach($results as $result){
    $html[$i]['label']=$result->name.', '.get_country_row($result->country_id)->name;

  $html[$i]['value']=$result->name;
$i++;
}
echo json_encode($html);
```

This can be used directly no need to convert in jquery part as the structure is already matching.

Comment: i try but same output

Comment: @BhavinSasapra and what is that output.

Comment: console get me output and display proper result but suggestions will not come.

Comment: @BhavinSasapra  in success of ajax try  `response(data);`

Comment: ohh! what is this i try before so much and now this is working thank you dear. solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the string that you trying to echo. You will notice that it's not valid json. It ends with comma before the bracket

```
// This is valid
[
  { label: "Rajoli, India", value: "Rajoli" }
]

//this is invalid
[
  { label: "Rajoli, India", value: "Rajoli" },
]
```

Insteadof creating it yourself you can use the `json_encode` function to parse php array into json

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $data[] = [
               "label" => $result->name.', '.get_country_row($result->country_id)->name, 
               "value" =>$result->name
    ];
}
//Now parse to json
echo json_encode($data);
```

You can also decide which side makes the formatting correct `{"label": "some string", "value": "data"}`

The second issue might be related with that you try to `$.map` label and value into objects

```
$("#location_suggetion").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request,response) {
        $.ajax ({
            url: base_url+'data_check/get_location',
            data: {term: request.term},
            dataType: "json", // This is right
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                response( data); // already mapped in backend
            } 
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: please tell me why this is invalid?

Comment: Thank you for reply but if i use simple source with this format this runs perfectly.

Comment: If you are able to console log the results from the success callback. And you see there array of objects then from this point it should go well. Please also look at dataType if change  jsonp to json helps.

Comment: Sorry dear but i try all methods

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your JSON format returned by php code. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var arr = [];
        var availableTags = [];

        $.ajax({
            'url'   : 'getdata.php',
            'method': 'get',
            success : function(response){
                arr = JSON.parse(response);

                availableTags = Object.keys(arr).map(function (key) { return arr[key]; });
            },
            async   : false
        });

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });  
    </script>
```

Php:

```
 <?php
    require('connect.php');

    $getDetails = "SELECT id, concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as name FROM test.datatables_demo";
    $details    = mysqli_query($con, $getDetails);

    $response = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($details) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details))
        {
            $response[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: get me console error SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 3

Answer (score 0):

Conver `Array` to `Json`

```
$term = $this->input->get('term');
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `tb_cities` WHERE name LIKE "'.$term.'%" LIMIT 0,6');
$results = $query->result();
$html = array();
foreach($results as $result){
    $html[]= array("label" => $result->name.",".get_country_row($result->country_id)->name,
                  "value" => $result->name);
}

echo json_encode($html,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: i try but same output